# issue using Pinia store with TypeScript (error ts(2322))

Tags: typescript, vue.js, openlayers, pinia

i created a map-store using pinia with the following code.

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { Map } from 'ol';

export const useMapStore = defineStore('map', {
  state: () => ({
    map: null as Map | null
  }),
  getters: {
    mainMap(): Map | null {
      return this.map;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    defineMap(map: Map) {
      this.map = map;
    },
    getLayerByName(name: string) {
      if (!this.map) {
        return null;
      } else {
        return this.map
          .getLayers()
          .getArray()
          .find(layer => layer.get('name') == name);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

However, typescript give me the following error :

```
  Type '{ on: MapEventHandler<EventsKey>; once: MapEventHandler<EventsKey>; un: MapEventHandler<void>; resizeObserver_: { ...; }; ... 67 more ...; dispose: () => void; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Map': renderComplete_, loaded_, boundHandleBrowserEvent_, maxTilesLoading_, and 51 more.ts(2322)
```

I tried to set map as only Map type like this :

```
  state: () => ({
    map: Map
  }),
  getters: {
    mainMap(): Map {
      return this.map;
    }
  },
```

But then i got this error :

```
  Type '{ on: MapEventHandler<EventsKey>; once: MapEventHandler<EventsKey>; un: MapEventHandler<void>; resizeObserver_: { ...; }; ... 67 more ...; dispose: () => void; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Map': renderComplete_, loaded_, boundHandleBrowserEvent_, maxTilesLoading_, and 51 more.ts(2322)
```

How can i fix this issue ?

Comment: Type incompatibility is caused by that Pinia simplifies state type to infer it and processes its keys, and Map class contains private keys that are known to cause the incompatibility. this.map has a type contained of public members, `{[k in keyof Map]: Map[k]}`. `mainMap(): Map | null {` - don't assert a type, let pinia do type inference. If it's necessary to return proper Map type then do `mainMap() { return this.map as unknown as Map` instead. If this is the whole store, it may be not a good idea to use reactive store for non-reactive service because it causes more troubles than it solves